# How to move to end of Scrollbar after adding QWidget into the QScrollArea

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to do scrolling to end after adding Qwidget. My pyqt5 program

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle('Window')
        MainWindow.resize(600, 600)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)

        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 600, 500))
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.scrollAreaWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 600, 500))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidget)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 515, 200, 70))
        self.pushButton.setText('Click me!')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_label_to_scrollArea)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    def add_label_to_scrollArea(self):
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('dummy text dummy text')
        self.scrollAreaWidgetLayout.addWidget(label)

        self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().setValue(10000) # <-- move to end
```

After clicking "Click", create a Qlabel, add it to the "scrollAreaWidget", and go to the end. But that didn't really happen.

See the demo below. Each time you click it should add a Qlabel and move it to the end.

my python program demo

[image]

EDIT: Added a push button with the ability to go to the end.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        ...
        self.pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 515, 200, 70))
        self.pushButton2.setText('end')
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.go_to_the_end)
    ...

    def go_to_the_end(self):
        self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().setValue(10000)
```

It works. Why does it work well alone? my python program demo2:

[image: my python program demo2]

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behavior is that it takes some time for the scroll area and its scrollbars to adjust themselves according to the contents of the viewport.

While a single shot QTimer could be used whenever a widget is added, there is no absolute guarantee that it will be fired when the scoll area/bars have been correctly adjusted, so the solution is to connect to the scroll bar [`rangeChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#rangeChanged) signal: whenever the contents of the viewport change the size requirements, the scroll bar range (actually, its maximum) will be adjusted accordingly.

In order to correctly achieve this, a *unique connection* must be used (to avoid multiple connections and calls) and the signal *must* be disconnected as soon as the scroll bar has been moved:

```
    def add_label_to_scrollArea(self):
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('dummy text dummy text')
        self.scrollAreaWidgetLayout.addWidget(label)
        try:
            self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().rangeChanged.connect(
                self.scrollToBottom, QtCore.Qt.UniqueConnection)
        except:
            # the connection already exists, do not connect again
            pass

    def scrollToBottom(self):
        scrollBar = self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar()
        scrollBar.rangeChanged.disconnect(self.scrollToBottom)
        scrollBar.setValue(scrollBar.maximum())
```

An important and unrelated suggestion: you should **never** modify the files generated by `pyuic` (nor try to mimic their behavior): those files are meant to be used **only** as imported modules. You can read how to correctly use those files in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).
Also, fixed geometries should always be avoided, and [`layout managers`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html) should be used instead.